# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allegroai'

Tags: python, clearml

I am trying to use [ClearML](https://clear.ml/docs/latest/docs/getting_started/mlops/mlops_first_steps).

The only line in my file is

```
from allegroai import Dataset, DatasetVersion
```

which yields

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allegroai'
```

Looks like some pip package is missing, but I couldn't for the life of me find it in the docs.

What should I pip install?

**Not working:**

- `pip install clearml-agent`
- `pip install clearml` and `clearml-init` as in [here](https://clear.ml/docs/latest/docs/getting_started/ds/ds_first_steps)
- `pip install allegroai`

Comment: May this help? https://github.com/allegroai/clearml/issues/545

Comment: @FranciscoPuga `(py37) noam@3828a9c0b7b5:~$ clearml-agent --docker init 
usage: clearml-agent [-h] [--help] [--version] [--config-file CONFIG_FILE] [--debug]
                     {execute,build,list,daemon,config,init} ...
clearml-agent: error: unrecognized arguments: --docker
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allegroai package should be taken from ClearML PyPi server.
This is only for paying customers (I think), and the way to retrieve it is by:

1. Going to ClearML website (login with username/company).
2. Press the ? on the top right of the screen (next to your user icon) and choose the first one
   [image: 1]